# How to rotate ImageView by clockwise

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation

I have sliding up panel and in the titlebar of that panel I have ImageView as in the picture. How to rotate to 180* by clockwise that ImageView when user slide panel up and anti-clockwise when slide down.

For sliding that panel I have method:

```
@Override
public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
     Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);

     //Animation here
}
```

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use two different images.

Comment: @Guanxi hello, how are you? Do you understand my question? I dont need only to change ImageView. I need to rotate by clockwise. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer, I have used this in my previous project. You could accept my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate a view without animation:

- `view.setRotation(float)` sets the degrees that the view is
  rotated around the pivot point. Increasing values result in clockwise
  rotation.
- `view.setRotationX(float)` sets the degrees that the view is
  rotated around the horizontal axis through the pivot point.
  Increasing values result in clockwise rotation from the viewpoint of
  looking down the x axis. When rotating large views, it is recommended to    adjust the camera distance accordingly.
- `view.setRotationY(float)` sets the degrees that the view is
  rotated around the vertical axis through the pivot point. Increasing
  values result in counter-clockwise rotation from the viewpoint of
  looking down the y axis. When rotating large views, it is recommended to adjust the camera distance accordingly.

If you want to use animation:

- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations (recommended)
- https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView
- https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator
- https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews
- https://gist.github.com/simon-heinen/9795036
- https://gist.github.com/methodin/5678214
- https://www.google.com/ :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to mark this as an answer but I can't leave comments yet, I was able to get Apurva's solution working correctly but I had to use this instead of getApplicationContext(), I had to use this because of where I was setting the animation from, the code in my application where I am attaching the animation looks like this...

```
ImageView billysArm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

    Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);

    billysArm.startAnimation(rotate);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hello Nick! In my case changes of ImageView must depents on how far panel opened from the button. ImageView change gradually and not by timer. Most od solution that i found had timers. But in my case rotate depends on how far panel opened... Do you have another ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking exactly, but if I do understand you correctly, The timers aren't necessarily needed and I have actually found that if I change the xml that is used for the rotation to be like this...  
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="4"  and take out the second rotation that was provided in the example above it does a smooth rotation and goes back without needing the timer and just activates on click

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out, setting an animation for your e.g. `ImageView`

```
@Override
public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
     Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);

    // Locate view
    ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    // Create an animation instance
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 180.0f, pivotX, pivotY);

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(10000);               // duration in ms
    an.setRepeatCount(0);                // -1 = infinite repeated
    an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
    an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation

    // Aply animation to image view
    iv.setAnimation(an);
}
```

Comment: Hello @marcus what mean pivotX pivotY here? By the way changes of ImageView depends on how far panel from the botton. But still now I dont know how to make that. Here slideOffset says how far panel from the bottom. I used it to change the color of panel gradually as in the picture. But here as I understand you have timer which is not what I want. =(

Comment: You can setDuration to 0... @Nurzhan Nogerbek

Comment: Hello @marcus I am mot sure that you undderstand my question. In my case changes of ImageView must depents on how far panel opened from the button. ImageView change gradually and not by timer. Most of solution that i found had timers. But in my case rotate depends on how far panel opened... Do you have another ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek pivotX and pivotY are the coordinates around which the image should be rotated.
You may use slideOffset value to check if it surpassed the ImageView Anchor point and then trigger the rotation animation as suggested above